# Can Not able to Build idoubs for armv7, armv7s and arm64 architecuture

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries, iphone-5, armv7, arm64

I am getting linker error on building idoubs for  armv7 ,armv7s and arm64 architecuture.Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the linker error you are getting.

Comment: ld: library not found for -lsrtp

Answer (score 0):

Use Standard Architectures only armv7s & armv7.